# Search linux partition for a specific sequence of bytes

Tags: linux, command-line

I lost an important file. I know what bytes the file begins with. How can I search the partition for the sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested by packages such as [ext3grep](http://www.xs4all.nl/~carlo17/) and [magicrescue](http://www.itu.dk/people/jobr/magicrescue/).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I search the partition for the sequence of bytes?

You can open partition device (such as /dev/hdc1) as a file in any hex editor/viewer your distribution has available (for example, midnight commander should be able to do that). Just make sure that you opened device in read-only mode and that your hex editor can handle files of that size.

Also, **one** byte won't be enough to find the file.

Comment: Where does the question say "one"?

Comment: I've never tried it, but opening a whole disk in an editor sounds like a bad idea. Also, it's usually `/dev/sd??` nowdays.

Comment: @Josh: "but opening a whole disk in an editor sounds like a bad idea", don't open it in **editor**, open it in **viewer**. For example, launch mc, select disk device, press F3. "Also, it's usually `/dev/sd??`" that depends on distribution and hardware. I still have several `/dev/hd??` on my 64bit Slackware 13.

Comment: You did say " **editor** / viewer ". As for `hd`/`sd`, forget it - it's no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a forensics tool called [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) which can help recover files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that it isn't the best solution, but you can grep the device, for example:

```
sudo grep `echo -e "\x11\x22\x33\x44"` /dev/hdc1
```

This will search the byte string `0x11 0x22 0x33 0x44` in `/dev/hdc1`, returning a boolean result.

Comment: That will return a phrase saying something like: "The binary file /dev/hdc1 matches". So a boolean result.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, **grep** does return a 'boolean' result for binary files. Either way, though, your code won't help the questioner recover his file.

Comment: No, it won't, but if he has no luck with `grep` there's no need to bother further with that.